# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass an image taken from ImageGrab from a class method. But it returns None. The im.show() inside takeSS() works.

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

class Manager():
    def takeSS(self):
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1980,200))
            im.show()
            return im 


m = Manager()

img = m.takeSS()
img.show()
```

console:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
```

Comment: Why do you have the if statement inside the function? It evaluates to false, so the block will not executed and None will be returned. Now you try to call show on None and this is not possible.

Comment: Please, *always* include the **full** traceback for your error. We now have to *guess* it is the *second* `img.show()` call that throws the exception rather than be able to confirm it from the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard in the middle of your method. That's a *very unusual place* for that test.

Unless this script is run as the main script, your `Manager.takeSS()` method will always return `None`, leading to your error.

Remove the `if` test from there altogether. It may have place *outside* of the class though:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

class Manager():
    def takeSS(self):
        im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1980,200)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
        im.show()
        return im

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Manager()        
    img = m.takeSS()
    img.show()
```

The code in the `if` test is now only run if you use this module as a script. That same block will not run when you use `import yourmodule`.

Comment: That works. If I ormit the __name__== "__main__" I'll get some other error. I'll have to dig into what it is it exactly does another time. But this work, so I'll continue onwards. Thanks alot :)